# How to reorder columns under multiple indexes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
Set Adjuvant    Route   Organ   Up  Down
set7    FOO ID  LV  11  14
set7    BAR ID  LV  17  15
set7    QUX ID  LV  10  22
set7    FOO ID  SP  14  13
set7    BAR ID  SP  13  8
set7    QUX ID  SP  11  18
set7    FOO ID  LN  25  25
set7    BAR ID  LN  38  16
set7    QUX ID  LN  53  18
```

And I have read and reorganize it with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.io.parsers.read_table("http://dpaste.com/3QB2YQX.txt")
df = df.pivot(index="Adjuvant",columns="Organ")

# Remove unwanted index name
df.drop('Set',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.drop('Route',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
df.columns.names = (None,None)

ndf = df.reindex(sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: x.lower()))
```

Which makes this data frame:

```
In [35]: ndf
Out[35]:
     Up         Down
     LN  LV  SP   LN  LV  SP
BAR  38  17  13   16  15   8
FOO  25  11  14   25  14  13
QUX  53  10  11   18  22  18
```

What I want to do is to render the columns under `UP/DOWN`indexes from `LN, LV, SP` to `LV, SP, LN`. How can I do it?

Comment: what is you expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=set_levels#setting-metadata):

```
In [3]: ndf[ndf.columns.set_levels(['LV', 'SP','LN'], level=1)]
Out[3]:
     Up         Down
     LV  SP  LN   LV  SP  LN
BAR  17  13  38   15   8  16
FOO  11  14  25   14  13  25
QUX  10  11  53   22  18  18
```

This is kinda undocumented on the site there is no dedicated page but if you do a tab-lookup to display the docstring it shows this:

```
Signature: ndf.columns.set_levels(levels, level=None, inplace=False, verify_integrity=True)
Docstring:
Set new levels on MultiIndex. Defaults to returning
new index.

Parameters
----------
levels : sequence or list of sequence
    new level(s) to apply
level : int or level name, or sequence of int / level names (default None)
    level(s) to set (None for all levels)
inplace : bool
    if True, mutates in place
verify_integrity : bool (default True)
    if True, checks that levels and labels are compatible

Returns
-------
new index (of same type and class...etc)


Examples
--------
>>> idx = MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, u'one'), (1, u'two'),
                                  (2, u'one'), (2, u'two')],
                                  names=['foo', 'bar'])
>>> idx.set_levels([['a','b'], [1,2]])
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'foo', u'bar'])
>>> idx.set_levels(['a','b'], level=0)
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'foo', u'bar'])
>>> idx.set_levels(['a','b'], level='bar')
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [u'a', u'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'foo', u'bar'])
>>> idx.set_levels([['a','b'], [1,2]], level=[0,1])
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'foo', u'bar'])
File:      c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py
Type:      method
```

Comment: @jezrael unclear what you're saying the column orders is different the column values remain with the newly ordered columns

Comment: @EdChum: How do you `do a tab-lookup`? I mean what command do you use?

Comment: if you're using `ipython` then you can lookup the docstring so `ndf[ndf.columns.set_levels(` and then press `tab` key will open the docstring

Comment: @EdChum: I cannot reproduce. When I do that It gave me `Display all 350 possibilities? (y or n)` etc. Any setting I have to enable?

Comment: sounds like a bug in your installation not sure what to suggest worth searching on SO to see if others have experienced the same issue, actually try Shift+Tab depending on your version of ipython the tab-complete key sequence may be different